# What do you call this programming pattern?

Tags: javascript, groovy

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in JavaScript and can't seem to find the right words to Google for it. It's a fairly common pattern.

```
someOperation(obj) { resultOfSomeOperation -> 
    anotherOperation(resultOfSomeOperation)
}
```

Presumably someOperation is a method that takes as arguments an `obj`, and a function with signature `result -> ??`. What do you call this?

Comment: What programming language your example is in? If it's about JS could you create a valid JS example that demonstrates an idea.

Comment: The JS equivalent seems to be ```someOperation(obj, function (resultOfSomeOperation) { anotherOperation(resultOfSomeOperation); });```

Comment: This looks like a mix of CoffeeScript and normal JavaScript syntax.

Comment: in Ruby, the `->` is a shortcut for `lambda.new` - in other word, you create a new function object by using `->` with a block of code: `-> { ...block of code... }`. Arguments can be added too: `-> {|arg1, arg2, ...| ...code...}`

Comment: First, figure out what language you are trying to use. Then Google "-> {LANG_NAME}" where {LANG_NAME} is the name of the programming language you are trying to use.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Perhaps your syntax has a typo, consider the fat arrow functions that ES6 includes.

Comment: I think the pattern you are looking for is called the "no-op" pattern. `function(x) { foo(x); }` is exactly equivalent to in all respects to `foo`. What does `obj` do in your pseudo-code?

Comment: It is closure in Groovy. http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the pattern you're pointing to is the "Callback" pattern, or more generally "Higher Order Functions", in which a function takes in a function as a parameter, and then uses the passed in function in some way.  Some examples would be Each, Map, Reduce, etc... These often use lambda functions.

Here's some information on these topics: [Callbacks on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29), [JavascriptIsSexy Callbacks](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/), [Eloquent Javascript Chapter 5](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html).

I'm leaning on Javascript examples, because that's the tag you used.  Feel free to ask me clarifying questions and I can explain them further.

Here's an example:

```
var exampleArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

exampleArray.map(function(num){
  return num * 2
});
// Returns [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
```

As you can see, map makes use of the anonymous function that was passed in.  Map applies the given function to each element of the array, and returns those outputs to a new array.  This could also be done by defining the function ahead of time, and passing it in by name.

```
var exampleArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var doubleValue = function(num) {
  return num * 2;
};

exampleArray.map(doubleValue);
// Returns [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

The pattern I'm referring to is when you chain multiple functions (usually lambdas) on a monadic object. `.map` is a great example.
It's easy to do in Scala and very idiomatic, but seems to just lead to callback hell in JS (not true monads).

Comment: Maybe if you provide a more detailed example of what you're talking about I can be more helpful.  You can definitely chain these things together.  For example: `[1,2,3,4,5].map(func).filter(func).reduce(func)` sort of chaining is totally viable.  If you're getting stuck in callback hell perhaps you should look into promises?  (Bluebird or Q)